# AutoFilter - Find out if second row of Visible Cells is blank

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that autofilters a worksheet based on either the first criteria, and then the second if no criteria is returned. The **conditional statement** is where I need help, it keeps on erroring even if there is data in the first cell of the second row (I obviously don't want to include the headers):

```
With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Range("A1:F1")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="FirstTest"

        'See if first cell in second row is blank
        If (.Offset(2,1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "") Then

            'if blank, change criteria
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="SecondTest"
        End If

   End With
End With
```

I know you can use VBA.Array's for multiple criteria, but this gets more complex, I merely need to now how to reference the visible data in the second row.

Thankyou in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Range("A1:F1")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="FirstTest"

        'See if first cell in second row is blank
        If (.Parent.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count < 2) Then

            'if blank, change criteria
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="SecondTest"
        End If

   End With
End With
```

Comment: Sorry I jumped the gun, this is working without errors but not accurately.
I have 10 rows on the screen (1 being the headings) and it's returning 126. If I filter down to 3 visible, it returns 18. Any ideas how this is even possible?

Comment: Oh! It's counting the cells, not the rows.Yahtzee. Thanks mate, your solution was definitely correct, I'll just update it slightly to count the rows.

Comment: The .Rows.Count was sometimes returning some odd results, but to fix this I just divided the cell count by the amount of columns I had:
rowCount = .Parent.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count / 6

Comment: Try: `.Parent.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count < 2`